# Definition of  face of a polyhedron

Tags: geometry, combinatorics

Let $P$ be a polyhedron in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\omega \in \mathbb{R}^n$, viewed as a linear functional

$\text{face}_{\omega}= \{ u \in P : \omega\cdot u \geq \omega\cdot v\mbox{ for all }v \in P \}$.

How does this definition match with general notion of the face of a polyhedron?

Comment: This is the generalized notion of a "face", in which (in three dimensions) vertices, edges, and faces are all included. For example, consider the unit cube $[0,1]^3$. Try $\omega = (1,1,1)$, $\omega = (1,1,0)$, and $\omega = (1,0,0)$ and see what "faces" you get.

Comment: Well, I understand that but how do I know that every face according to this generalized definition is also  a "face" according to the old definition.

Comment: It's a "face" in the old sense when $\omega$ is normal to one of the faces in the old sense.  A choice of $\omega$ is a linear function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which restricts to a linear function on the polyhedron.  The face of $\omega$ is the locus of points of the polyhedron maximizing the function (exists by compactness yadda yadda), which is going to be one of the lower-dimensional cells.

Comment: *at least one of (only one, if the polyhedron is convex).